# Exists sequence converging to $0$ in $\mathbb{R}$, $1$ in $\mathbb{Q}_2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Does there exist a sequence of elements $x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots$ of elements of $\mathbb{Q}$ that converges to $0$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and converges to $1$ in $\mathbb{Q}_2$?

Comment: $x_n=1/(2^n+1)$? (essentially Mathmo123's +1 answer)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I think your approach makes it more explicit. My approach was to try to manipulate a sequence I know, which coincidentally gave something similar to you.

Comment: @Mathmo123 Explaining how you arrived at the example IMHO adds to the usefulness of the answer. And, that is the #1 cool series behaving differently in the two metrics, so it is natural to apply a fractional rational function to it to get the desired limits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're after a sequence $(x_n)\subset\mathbb Q$ such that $$|x_n|_\infty\to 0, \quad |x_n-1|_2\to 0$$as $n\to\infty$.

The sequence $$y_n=\sum_{i=0}^n 2^i =2^n-1$$
Converges to $-1$ in $\mathbb Q_2$, so by the continuity of the function $f(x)=-\frac 1x$ at $-1$, $$x_n:= -\frac 1{y_n}\to 1$$in $\mathbb Q_2$ as $n\to\infty$. Clearly $x_n\to 0$ in $\mathbb R$.

More generally, if $f(x)= \frac {a(1+x)-b}x$, then $f(y_n)\to a$ in $\mathbb R$ and $b$ in $\mathbb Q_2$.